# Number of Spanning Trees of the complete graph on n vertices, different proof

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I'm aware of proofs for this question such as using Kirchoffs matrix theorem or using a bijection to get $N^{N-2}$ however my first instinct was to use the idea there are ${N\choose 2}$ possible edges in $k_n$ and that any tree with $N$ vertices has $N-1$ edges therefore I tried to simplify:

${{N\choose 2}\choose N-1} =  {(N(N-1))/2}!/{(N-1)!}$ where I believe the denominator gets eliminated after $(N-1)^2$ iterations of the numerator.

This is as far as I get with this though, I'm quite new to combinatorics and factorials in terms of simplifying and manipulating equations. The main question is can I get to final answer this way and how would I simply this further?

Comment: You are calculating the number of ways to choose $N-1$ of the edges. Why would you expect such a choice to always give a tree? Surely you can easily choose $N-1$ edges that includes one or more cycles (and by necessity leave some of the vertices unconnected), so your calculation gives a number that is far too large.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ah yeah of course I'm stupid, thanks

Comment: You can check it for $N=4$. You find $\binom63=20$ subgraphs of $K_4$ with three edges. These are the $4^{4-2}=16$ spanning trees, but also $4$ triangles. For larger $N$ it gets messier.